# different computer different output

Tags: c, arrays, dev-c++

I compiled this code on my WxDev C++. By theory it should output the users' answer and the correct answer. It did, with an exception of array number 0 of the coranswers array, showing just a blank space. I tried compiling it on other PCs and the problem wasn't present. I tried reinstalling the WxDev, even as far as replacing it with codeblocks. Seems like the problem is on my PC. What should I do?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
char coranswers[20] = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'};
char answers[20];
int count;
int grade = 0;

for(count = 0; count < 20; count++){
          printf("No.%d ", count+1);
          scanf("%s", &answers[count]);
          }
for(count = 0; count < 20; count++){
          printf("No.%d ", count+1);
          printf("Your answers : %c\n", answers[count]);
          if(answers[count] == coranswers[count]){
                            grade++;
                            }
          else{
               printf("Wrong answer, correct answer is %c\n", coranswers[count]);
          }
          }
          return 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to read a string into a char array

```
scanf("%s", &answers[count]); // the format string should be "%c"
```

Comment: probably `" %c"` with whitespace, if it's supposed to ignore newlines.

Comment: Thanks, i did use %c and ended up messing the program, but after seeing Anton's answer, i tried using the whitespace and it worked .

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting a character.

Change the format specifier in your scanf from **%s** to **%c**

```
scanf("%c", &answers[count])
```

For the difference in output between different systems, this can be a reason.

```
scanf("%s", &answers[count])
```

Since `answers` is a **char** array, so you do not need **&** when you get a string. you are probably corrupting `&answers`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use `%s` only for even character, but a little differently ->

```
char temp[8];

scanf("%s", temp);
answers[count] = temp[0];
```